# Webpack builds but components don't render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I am developing in a windows environment for the first time (coming from OS).

I have built the basic foundation for a react app, and webpack builds without errors, but only the raw HTML renders.  I.e., the ReactDOM process seems to fail or something because my app component doesn't render at all.  Note that I leveraged code from an app I built in OS, wondering if that has something to do with it.

See code below.  Thank you for having a look.

**First my webpack.config.js file:**

```html
const webpack = require('webpack');
const UglifyJSPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const path = require('path');
const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

const SRC_DIR = path.join(__dirname, '/client/src');
const DIST_DIR = path.join(__dirname, '/client/dist');

module.exports = {
    entry: `${SRC_DIR}\\index.js`,
    output: {
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'client/dist'),
      filename: 'bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.jsx?/,
          include: SRC_DIR,
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          query: {
            presets: ['react', 'es2015'],
            plugins: ['syntax-dynamic-import'],
          },
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
          include: SRC_DIR,
        },
      ],
    },
    resolve: {
      extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
    },
    plugins: [
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
          NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('development'),
        },
      }),
      new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
      // ,
      // new UglifyJSPlugin(),
    ],
  };
```

**Next my html file:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="https://orig00.deviantart.net/15e4/f/2011/116/f/4/color_wheel_dock_icon_by_andybaumgar-d3ezjgc.png">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <title>SysAdmin Microservices</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Node Microservices Server Documentation</h1>
        <div id="root"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**My index.js file with the ReactDOM.render call:**

```html
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './containers/App.jsx';

ReactDOM.render( <App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**Last of all my App.js file:**

```html
import React from 'react';

class App extends React {

    render() {
        console.log('app render has been invoked <-- this never logs to the console ');
        return (
            <h1>This is the text that does not render in the browser.</h1>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: note that my bundle.js file does in fact include the text from App.js that is not rendering to the browser.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have your `bundle.js` referenced from the index page, else it won't load any of your JS. Will vary based on your folder structure, but something along the lines of this should work:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="dist/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Or you could use a Webpack plugin like [html-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin) to inject your bundled JS as a part of your build process.

Comment: you solved my bug!  Such a simple oversight on my part!  Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: No worries, such an easy thing to miss when you're trying to work through things!

Answer (score 0):

You can add the script to your bundle manually or use `html-webpack-plugin`.

This plugin will handle inserting scripts/style to the index html ([and more](https://github.com/jantimon/html-webpack-plugin)) automatically.

**Steps:**

- Install the plugin: `npm install --save-dev html-webpack-plugin`
- Require it in webpack config: `const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin')`
- Add the plugin to the plugin config:

  ```
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
        template: './src/index.html',
        filename: 'index.html',
    }),
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env': {
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify('development'),
      },
    }),
    new ExtractTextPlugin("styles.css"),
    // ,
    // new UglifyJSPlugin(),
  ]
  ```

Comment: Thank you @shmotam!